# IndexedDB cursors

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

my question is pretty simple.
I can't understand an example from the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor) about iterating a result from an IndexedDB. Specifically, I can't see any loop used for iteration. There is no for/while/do cycle. Here is the example:

```
function displayData() {
  var transaction = db.transaction(['rushAlbumList'], "readonly");
  var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('rushAlbumList');

  objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor) {
       var listItem = document.createElement('li');
       listItem.innerHTML = cursor.value.albumTitle + ', ' + cursor.value.year;
       list.appendChild(listItem);  

       cursor.continue();
    } else {
       console.log('Entries all displayed.');
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 6):

The "loop" happens implicitly. Each successful advance of the cursor results in a "success" event, which will trigger a call to the handler assigned to the "onsuccess" property of the request. Thus, the iteration happens because of this line:

```
cursor.continue();
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. Pretty ugly way how to achieve it. I would prefer an explicit loop. But thanks for an explanation...

Comment: @JiříLechner the mechanism is asynchronous, because the accesses to the database may take (a small amount of) time.

Comment: indexedDB is meant to be used declaratively, not imperatively. There is chance that you will be able to write imperative async js later this year once some js features change in newer versions of js. But I wouldn't keep your hopes up and would learn how to write declarative code.

Comment: While this may work (I honestly have no idea) I have never seen it written like this. the `if(cursor)` in the above example is always written as `while(cursor)` - maybe thats a change since this QaA, but in case others end up here and are also confused.